# Locate and merge duplicate rows in a data.frame but ignore column order

Tags: r, duplicates, dataframe, plyr

I have a data.frame with 1,000 rows and 3 columns.  It contains a large number of duplicates and I've used plyr to combine the duplicate rows and add a count for each combination as explained in [this thread](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/how-to-simplify-a-data-frame-and-add-the-counts-of-duplicate-rows-as-a-new-column-td3331655.html).

Here's an example of what I have now (I still also have the original data.frame with all of the duplicates if I need to start from there):

```
   name1    name2    name3     total
1  Bob      Fred     Sam       30
2  Bob      Joe      Frank     20
3  Frank    Sam      Tom       25
4  Sam      Tom      Frank     10
5  Fred     Bob      Sam       15
```

However, column order doesn't matter. I just want to know how many rows have the same three entries, in any order.  How can I combine the rows that contain the same entries, ignoring order?  In this example I would want to combine rows 1 and 5, and rows 3 and 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define another column that's a "sorted paste" of the names, which would have the same value of "Bob~Fred~Sam" for rows 1 and 5. Then aggregate based on that.

Brief code snippet (assumes original data frame is `dd`): it's all really intuitive. We create a `lookup` column (take a look and should be self explanatory), get the sums of the `total` column for each combination, and then filter down to the unique combinations...

```
dd$lookup=apply(dd[,c("name1","name2","name3")],1,
                                  function(x){paste(sort(x),collapse="~")})
tab1=tapply(dd$total,dd$lookup,sum)
ee=dd[match(unique(dd$lookup),dd$lookup),]
ee$newtotal=as.numeric(tab1)[match(ee$lookup,names(tab1))]
```

You now have in `ee` a set of unique rows and their corresponding total counts. Easy - and no external packages needed. And crucially, you can see at every stage of the process what is going on!

(Minor update to help OP:) And if you want a cleaned-up version of the final answer:

```
outdf = with(ee,data.frame(name1,name2,name3,
                           total=newtotal,stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
```

This gives you a neat data frame with the three all-important name columns, and with the aggregated totals in a column called `total` rather than `newtotal`.

Comment: This also worked (after I removed spaces from data.frame entries).  It also eliminates the step of manually copy/pasting data.  However, it leaves me with:


` name1 name2 name3 total        lookup newtotal`
1   Bob  Fred   Sam    30  Bob~Fred~Sam       45
2   Bob   Joe Frank    20 Bob~Frank~Joe       20
3 Frank   Sam   Tom    25 Frank~Sam~Tom       35`

Comment: Hmmm, can't get code block to work in comments...

however, ee displays the merged results without the updated totals and then beside it the merged results with the updated totals (and with ~ replacing the tabs between row entries).  I'm sure this is an easy fix, but I don't know R well enough (yet) to easily fix it...

Comment: Ok, I actually took the time to read through your code and think each action through and realized that the answer to my question was even more obvious than I had thought.  I just took the two new columns and inserted them into a new data.frame (and replaced the "~" with "  " just to make it easier to read).  Thanks!

Comment: The only downside to this solution is that now instead of three separate columns in the data.frame, all 3 elements are combined into 1 string - that might create problems down the road...

Comment: Hey, actually none of those are problems - see the additional `outdf` line in my answer which shows a way to tidy up (I thought keeping the original columns in `ee` would make things more transparent!). Re. your last comment - no, you still have the three original columns right there (the first three columns in `ee` and indeed in `outdf`)... the combined column is just a line of working really. Finally, it's really valuable to learn to do data frame operations this way. In the other method your **rows** change order (Bob/Fred/Sam is no longer 1st) which is very often not what you want. Cheers!

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks for the update - this is exactly what I need.  Also, thank you for the tip about list.files in the other comment - I was unaware of it.

Comment: You're most welcome. I know you can't upvote yet but your thanks are much appreciated :) Yep, I commonly use `list.files` with the argument `full=TRUE` as that automatically gives you the full filenames. (You can always use `basename` on the vector of full filenames if you want the "short" versions for some reason.) Another useful command is `file.info` which gives you various useful information on a file (or directory) - it needs the full filename of course. Try em out! Cheers :)

Answer (score 4):

Sort the index columns, then use `ddply` to aggregate and sum:

Define the data:

```
dat <- "   name1    name2    name3     total
1  Bob      Fred     Sam       30
2  Bob      Joe      Frank     20
3  Frank    Sam      Tom       25
4  Sam      Tom      Frank     10
5  Fred     Bob      Sam       15"

x <- read.table(text=dat, header=TRUE)
```

Create a copy:

```
xx <- x
```

Use `apply` to sort the columns, then aggregate:

```
xx[, -4] <- t(apply(xx[, -4], 1, sort))
library(plyr)
ddply(xx, .(name1, name2, name3), numcolwise(sum))
  name1 name2 name3 total
1   Bob Frank   Joe    20
2   Bob  Fred   Sam    45
3 Frank   Sam   Tom    35
```

Comment: Hasn't doing it this way changed the original data? The first line used to say "Bob, Fred, Sam"...?

Comment: @timp Yes, but since the OP said the order doesn't matter, that probably doesn't matter. Anyway, the original data is still in `x`. That's why I created a new object `xx`. But the reason why the row order is different is because `ddply` sorts the grouping variables before doing the aggregation.

Comment: Eek! That's why I tend to steer away from these new-fangled packages - I always find you really have to know them inside out otherwise you can easily get burned. Then again, I suppose sometimes you wouldn't mind your rows being reordered (though that'd be a nightmare for the kind of things I use R for). Thanks for the tips though :)

Comment: @TimP I think you are missing something here.If you aggregate the results, then row order is immaterial, since some rows are getting lost anyway.

Comment: Nope, I'm not missing anything. The expected effect of the operation is that duplicate rows (after reordering of columns) get eliminated - great. The unintended side effect is that the order of [unique] rows changes; the natural outcome would retain the order of unique rows. In fact, that's a great analogy - when I run a `unique` command, I expect to get the unique elements of the vector in the same order as they currently occur. If the elements were made unique but also reordered, maybe in some sense that's a legitimate "unique" - but it's simply not the most natural mathematical one :)

Comment: +1 for making me laugh :) If you think about it a while in terms of my unique function example I'm sure you'll see what I mean. Cheers :)

Comment: This worked perfectly - thanks!  Just had to remove the spaces from my data.frame entries (my fault for not giving a proper data example).  Andrie is correct - for this particular set of data the order of the content of each row does not matter, I just need to know which rows have the same 3 entries - so 1,2,3 , 1,3,2 , 3,1,2 , 3,2,1 , 2,1,3 , and 2,3,1 are all the same.  I do realize that this isn't a normal way to organize data - just happens to be what is needed in this case.

Comment: Also, is there a way to do this that removes the step of manually copy/pasting the data into "dat"?  I need to do this to 50 different data.frames and would like to automate it as much as possible.  Thanks!

Comment: When you say you have 50 different data frames, presumably they're stored on disk in some sort of csv format rather than in R memory? If so, you just want to loop over the files (use `list.files` to get a vector of names) and use `read.csv` or similar to load them into a data frame...

Comment: +1 for jdfinch - Absolutely correct :) It is really unusual for row order not to matter at all (that's exactly why the order function is so useful when manipulating data frames and behaves in a very well-definedl regular way) but in this example perhaps you don't care too much what order the rows are in. Just striking a note of caution that the rows were all changing order, that's all :)